# how to connect to MongoDB deployed in Kubernetes from Studio3t?

Tags: docker, mongodb, kubernetes

I'm wondering on how do I connect to a Kubernetes deployed mongoldb instance, I have been using studio3t its fairly easy to use when DB hosted on AWS and all. I am finding it difficult to connect to Kubernetes hosted mongodb which is exposed to outside world by NodePort.

Comment: What particularly are you having problems with? Your database will be exposed at some host via some port, even when running in Kubernetes. Can't you configure that when connecting?

Comment: It seems that I have to use username and password or ssh based authentication which I have not configured in kubernetes..studio3t client simply won't connect when I give ip without any key or username and password.

Comment: Please show some screenshots. Does it not work like this? https://cdn-web.studio3t.com/knowledge-base/wp-content/uploads/mongodb-localhost-800x397.png?x59548